# Use filter from test scope in web.xml

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a project that is used as a base for a number of different webapps. I'm trying to run it in "test" mode using the jetty-maven plugin.

The project is a multi-module project. The Filter is located in another module, which is a dependency of the module I'm trying to run, specified like so:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>X.X.X</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The filter class from that dependency is then added as a filter in web.xml:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>test</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.example.test.test.TestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>test</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Finally, the project is started via a call to the jetty-maven plugin (`mvn jetty:run-forked`) which is set up like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
    <configuration>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/test</contextPath>
            <descriptor>src/test/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
        </webApp>
        <useTestScope>true</useTestScope>
        <jvmArgs>some arguments</jvmArgs>
        <jettyXml>jetty.xml,jetty-ssl.xml,jetty-https.xml</jettyXml>
        <stopKey>stopJetty</stopKey>
        <stopPort>12345</stopPort>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The project runs and displays the index.html file, but the filter is never applied to any request. Is it possible to run a test-scope app the way I have it set up? What else could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

If the server started, without an error, then the filter was there.

Perhaps you could add logging to the filter `init()` or `doFilter()` to verify that it actually got run.

Also, if you are using `javax.websocket`, then those HTTP/1.1 WebSocket Upgrade requests will not be filterable.

Comment: It seems that neither method is being called. No websockets.